# If i'm making test cases using selenium web driver and cannot use selinium IDE, how else do i use it.?

Tags: selenium, ide, testcase

I cannot use the selenium IDE as i'm not allowed to use firefox. The website that i need to test doesnt have ID's for every tag. So i cannot even use that. My question is, how else do i use the locator object? Thats the argument in selinium.click or selinium.clickAt.

Comment: You aren't *required* to use the IDE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many other ways http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#selenium-webdriver-api-commands-and-operations

Just like with the IDE; by CSS, by xPath, by name, by class ...

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input"));
```